# Why using ? in this case is not working? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

My purpose is to assign the color of UIView from an existing image:

```
self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2")?)
```

As I understand, I don’t know whether this UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2") contains nil or a value, so: if it has value use it, and otherwise just consider the whole expression nil, and do nothing.

Why do I always get the error:

"Value of optional type 'UIImage' not unwrapped; Did you mean to use '!' or '?'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know whether your image exists or not, you should use *optional binding*, try this:

```
func setBGImage(myImageName: String) {
  if let bgColor = UIImage(named: myImageName) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: bgColor)
  }
}
```

If ***myImage*** exists, it will assign it to *bgColor*, in which is assigned to *self.view.backgroundColor*.

or, as stated before, if you know the image exists, just *forcibly unwrap it* by:

```
self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2")!)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Actually you probably want optional binding on both parts, so use a linked pair of optional binding statements.

Comment: @DuncanC, `UIColor(patternImage:)` isn't failable.  It returns a `UIColor` not a `UIColor?`.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**
Change the code to

```
self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2")!)
```

**Long answer**

First, `UIImage(named:)` is a 'failable initializer' .

If your filename `04_white_back_page2` does not exists in your project's resources, then the initializer `UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2")` fails and it becomes `nil`.

Since `UIColor(patternImage:)` only accepts `UIImage`, the swift compiler complained that your `UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2")`'s type is `UIImage?`.

You cans see the detail description about failable initializer on (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17)

However, you know `04_white_back_page2` is in your project or not(right?). Therefore, it's safe to 'unwrap' your expression with `!`. Use `!` to say the compiler that you are quite confident that the expression is not `nil`. Then `UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2")!` 's type is `UIImage` and the compiler is happy. If the trust is wrong, your application will die in runtime with the message `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

So, use `!` only when you are confident.

In general, you don't know your expression is `nil` or not. In the case, you should handle the both cases in this way.

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2") {
  self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: img)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the init method of `UIColor` that you are using (`patternImage`) does not expect an optional but an actual value (so a nill value is not allowed)

So either force unwrapping with '!'

```
self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2")!)
```

or make sure the image exists before creating the color.

The former is not safe as it will cause a runtime error if the image fails to load for whatever reason so I'll suggest you use the second option

Comment: But, I don't know whether the image exists or not. What is the concise way to express this case?

Comment: is the image part of your app resources or do you read it from an external source? either way if you expect that sometimes this image will not be available think of a default color to use (or a default image)

Comment: I mean in general case. Swift language is not perfect as I thought. It still depends on what the developer knows at first.

Answer (score 0):

> so: if it has value use it, and otherwise just consider the whole
>   expression nil, and do nothing

You are describing *optional chaining*.  In an *optional chain*, if a variable or expression might be `nil`, following it by a `?` allows you to unwrap it for the purposes of accessing members, methods, or an array access or dictionary look up.  If the variable or expression is `nil`, the whole expression is `nil`.

*Optional chaining* only works if the `?` is followed by a member name (property), a method call, or array/dictionary access `[]`.  It does nothing to just end with a `?`.  Furthermore, the result of an *optional chain* is always an optional value, so it wouldn't help you here anyway because the constructor for `UIColor` doesn't take an optional.  Unfortunately, you can't use *optional chaining* in the way you are attempting.  It would be nice if it just skipped the entire line if your `UIImage` were `nil`, but it doesn't work that way.

The proper way to handle this if you don't know for sure if the image exists is to use *optional binding* when you create the image:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "04_white_back_page2") {
    self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
}
```